# Xamarin Studio for Mac throwing exceptions in FSI - `seems` not to be loading core F# libs

Tags: xamarin, f#, mono, xamarin-studio

Sorry for all the long error messages!  I wonder if there is something wrong with my Xamarin, or Mono install which is breaking FSI on Xamarin? Default .Net runtime is Mono 4.6.2  Although I have installed Mono 4.8.0, Xamarin is running on 4.6.2

I wonder if these error messages mean that FSI isn't loading the System.Drawing module?  And why is **SOURCE_DIRECTORY** seemingly not working?  There are no errors displayed in the .fsx file but when loaded into FSI it doesn't work.

I've also got Visual Studio for Mac installed.  I'm just starting with F# (day 3) and this is the first time I've tried to open a System module so I've not idea if it ever worked.  Basic functions I write myself will evaluate in FSI.  I'm considering the possibility that the install has been screwed up somewhere and am wondering if I should just remove .Net, Xamarin and Mono and reinstall from scratch?  Is it possible for Visual Studio to interfere with Xamarin?

Going through the FSharp TV intro course I'm running the following errors

F# in a .fsx file:

```
open System.Drawing

let bitmap = new Bitmap(32,32)

let path = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/"

bitmap.Save (path + "large.png")
```

Loading the entire code block in FSI throws:

```
System.Exception: Generic Error [GDI+ status: GenericError]
   at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status status) [0x0007a] in <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.String filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo encoder, System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters encoderParams) [0x00043] in <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.String filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format) [0x0004c] in <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.String filename) [0x00008] in <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Image:Save (string)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0004>.$FSI_0004.main@ () [0x0003d] in <2545683d6122431b9ff3a69ce9ec460c>:0 
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0
```

Loading only **SOURCE_DIRECTORY** in FSI returns:

```
val it : string = "/"
```

which is weird because that's not the correct path

Loading the line: `let bitmap = new Bitmap(32,32)`

throws:

```
Stopped due to error
 System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier error
 The type 'Bitmap' is not defined at 2,4
```

Sending System.Drawing to FSI

throws:

```
Stopped due to error
 System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier error
 The value, constructor, namespace or type 'Drawing' is not defined at 2,7
```

Comment: Could you try the F# Interactive pad in Xamarin Studio? It is under View -> Pads -> F# Interactive.

Comment: hey Ashley, I've actually deleted Xamarin to see if it was that mono install which caused the bug.  F# Interactive was working fine before I removed it all.  I'm now using VSCode.  Same bug.  I can load other System modules though

Comment: Interesting! FWIW, a Xamarin team member was able to run the same code without issue. Seeing as it's also failing in VSCode, I'm wondering if something might not quite be right on your machine? Haven't seen any reports of VS Mac/Xamarin Studio interference other than the [Mono 4.8 requirement](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs-mac/preview/vs-mac-preview1/#Side_by_Side_Installation_with_Xamarin_Studio), but will keep an eye out just in case.

Comment: I also have `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`  return "/" on Visual Studio for Mac

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be hitting a Mono bug. I've found several reports of what looks like the same bug (though it's possible that it's several different bugs). The most useful one appears to be this Github issue: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2226

I don't know if that will help you; that issue appears to have been resolved by upgrading from Mono 3.2.8 to the latest version of Mono available at the time. But you're *already* running what appears to be the latest version of Mono available to you, so "upgrade to the latest Mono" may not be the advice for your problem. But it's the best advice I'm able to give.

Also, in doing that search, I found several people complaining that `libgdiplus` (Mono's implementation of the GDIPlus API) was buggy in various ways. So in your shoes, I might skip the `System.Drawing` examples and move on to a different part of the tutorial if you can't get `libgdiplus` to work.

P.S. The below is what I first wrote in answer to your question, but then I experimented and discovered that the `System.Drawing` namespace is automatically loaded in F# scripts without you needing to explicitly open it. Still, as an F# beginner, you may find the information below to be useful in other contexts, so I've left it in. Just be aware that what I said below about `System.Drawing` not being automatically opened was wrong.

**----- Not-quite-correct answer follows -----**

When writing an F# script in a `.fsx` file, you can't just do `open (namespace)`. You also have to tell F# where to find the .DLL with that namespace. In a compiled project (which uses `.fs` files), that information would be found in the `.fsproj` file. But for F# scripts (the `.fsx` format), there's no project file, so the script itself needs to specify which DLLs to load. You do this by the `#r` directive:

```
#r "/path/to/library.dll"
```

Or, if the DLL you're loading is installed in a standard system location such as the GAC (Global Assembly Cache), you can leave off the path and just do:

```
#r "library.dll"
```

There are a few DLLs that are automatically loaded whenever you run an F# script, such as `mscorlib.dll` that contains things like the `System` namespace. But the `System.Drawing` namespace is not one of those automatically-loaded DLLs. So before you can open the `System.Drawing` namespace, you have to put in the appropriate `#r` reference, like so:

```
#r "System.Drawing.dll"
open System.Drawing
```

Comment: thanks for your help!  I'm still not quite sure what is causing this.  I've tried removing xamarin.  Bug persists in VSCode, although I can load other System modules.  I'd like to remove the .Net install too but that seems like a real pain.. ><